# Time stored as a number of seconds since Monday in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

In lubridate package, a hms is a time stored as the number of seconds since 00:00:00. Therefore, if you run `as.hms(85)`, it returns `"00:01:25"`. I would like to have the same thing, but stored as the number of seconds since Monday 00:00:00. Therefore, I would like to have a function, say `as.day_of_week_hms()`, such that if you run `as.day_of_week_hms(85)`, it returns `"Monday 00:01:25"`. I would prefer a tidyverse solution because I love the philosophy of this "ecosystem"! Thanks.

Comment: How are you telling the function what day to compare against? It seems like you want to write a wrapper around `diff`, but I'm not sure where "Monday" comes from

Comment: 1970-01-05 is the first Monday since the UNIX Epoch so: `format(as.POSIXct("1970-01-05") + 85, "%A %T")`

Comment: I'm assuming they mean "since the most recent Monday".

Comment: The solution is likely just `60^2 * 24 * (current week day - 1) + current seconds of the day`. Thus locate the current weekday (in number) and the current second of the day, (regardless of which day) and insert into the equation for the result. This obviously assumes monday is the first day of the week.